# Open markdown filename under cursor like gf, and jump to the section?

Tags: key-bindings, multiple-files, filetype-markdown

I have the file /path/a.md which has many sections as follows:

```
# abc
this this the content of section abc
# def
this this the content of section abc
## defg
this this the content of subsection defg of def
```

And in an other file /path/b.md I have the the following:

```
I want to switch to def section by this link [section def in a.md](./a.md#def), 
yeh the file name and the section name are separated by "#" 
and this kind of link is also possible:[subsection defg in a.md](./a.md##defg)
```

Comment: On my setup `gf` didn't opened the file because `#` was in `isfname`, so using `set isfname-=#` allowed `gf` to jump to the file. Now to go to a particular section I don't think there is a built-in way to do so but developing a function to override `gf` should not be too hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function is not thoroughly tested but it should provide a good enough bootstrap for your own experiments.

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
function! s:MDGoToSection()
    let raw_filename = expand('<cfile>')
    let arg = substitute(raw_filename, '\([^#]*\)\(#\{1,6\}\)\([^#]*\)', '+\/\2\\\\s\3 \1', 'g')
    execute "edit" arg
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <key> :call <SID>MDGoToSection()<CR>
```

[image: gf++]

**Explanation**

The filename under the cursor is split into three groups:

```
\([^#]*\)......................... everything before the first #              
         \(#\{1,6\}\)............. 1 to 6 #
                     \([^#]*\).... everything after #######
```

and reordered into a proper argument for `:edit`:

```
+\/\2\\\\s\3 \1
```

which should split `./foo.md##bar` into `./foo.md`, `##`, and `bar`, and finally pass `+/##\\sbar ./foo.md` to `:edit`:

```
:edit +/##\\sbar ./foo.md
```

Comment: Damn you was a few second faster and your solution is much more elegant, I'm a little bit jealous ;)

Comment: @statox, hehe… check out the edited version for even more élégance.

Comment: Ahah well done!

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the comments on my setup gf didn't opened the file because `#` was in `isfname`, so using `set isfname-=#` allowed `gf` to jump to the file.

As I also said I think the feature to go to a section of the file is not built in so you can try this function:

```
function! MarkdownGF()
    " Get the filename under the cursor
    let cfile=expand('<cfile>')
    " Separate the filename from the section
    let parts=split(cfile, '#')

    " No section marked
    if (len(parts) == 1)
        execute "normal! gf"
    " There was a subsection in the file name
    else
        execute "e " . parts[0]
        let pattern = "^" . repeat('\#',len(parts)-1) . "\\\s*" . parts[len(parts)-1] . "$"
        call search(pattern, 'w')
    endif
endfunction
```

The function is to be called when the cursor is on the file you want to open. It will go to the file and if a subsection is specified it will search for it.

To make it easier to call you could remap the function only on markdown buffers:

```
autocmd! Filetype markdown nnoremap <buffer> gf :call MarkdownGF()<CR>
```