# README.md (markdown) - jump to infile link

Tags: filetype-markdown

While reading a markdown file, specifically using GitHub markdown, vim interprets hyperlinks correctly. It seems like it would be able to jump to the corresponding section in the file. Is there a key combination when on top of a

```
[Section 1](#sec1)
```

link to jump to the corresponding tag

```
# Section 1 <a name="sec1" />
```

? Here I imagine the cursor sitting on top of "Section 1".

Other than `/sec1` of course... (and variants).

Comment: [strongly related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9344/1841)